# c - passing argument 1 from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, vector

I have this code, very simple and it gives me the error on function max(), when I call it from the latest printf:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float max(float v[], int n){
  float maxim = v[0];
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    if(maxim < v[i]){
      maxim = v[i];
    }
  }
  return maxim;
}

void main(){
  int v[10], n;
  float x;

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    printf("Introduza %d de 10 números: ", i+1);
    scanf(" %f", &x);
    v[i] = x;
  }

  printf("Indique o número de elementos que pretende avaliar: ");
  scanf(" %d", &n);

  printf("O maior valor introduzido entre os %d primeiros números foi %f", n, max(v,n));
}
```

Text is in Portuguese, but that doesn't matter. 
The error:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘max’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
```

I saw a few threads but I think this is different. Can somebody help me?

Comment: The passed `v` in `max(v,n)` is an `int` array, but `max` wants a `float` array.

Comment: So nooby :( How could I miss that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You probably want `float v[10]` in `main`, because you are assigning `float x` to each element.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that, thanks. Put your answer and I'll mark it when possible. :) Now it runs perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The passed `v` in `max(v,n)` is an `int` array, but `max` wants a `float` array.

You also need `float v[10]` in `main`, because you are assigning `float x` to each element.

But I would use `double` unless there is a very good reason why you must use `float`.

Aside: please note that `main` should be

```
int main(void)
```

Comment: I'm using float because I'm folowing the exercises, and it asked to implement float max(float v[], int n) that receives a vector of reals (don't know if it's the correct term) e the number of elements to evaluate. It returns the biggests number among the first n of the vector.

Comment: Using old reference materials?

Comment: The book was edited in 2013 and first written in 1999. Yes old school material :D

Comment: Why should main be 'int main(void)' because of some errors that may occur?

Comment: Because that is the definiton of `main` in 2017, when no arguments are passed. Although some compilers for embedded code might not want that, when `main` never returns to an OS.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
void main(){
  int v[10], n;
  float x;
```

To:

```
void main(){
  float v[10];
  int n;
  float x;
```

Comment: `void main()` is at best an implementation-dependent signature for `main()`. To agree with the Standard, should be `int main(void)`, or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.